# How to apply spacy to extract organisation name, location from any text?

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition

Text : "PATANJALT MEGA SoRE
AUND PUNE411007
AROGYADAYI
MOB: :7507489862
GST NO : 27ABcFA1565H1ZM"

How to use spacy to extract such information?

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')  
for entity in doc.ents:    
    print(entity.text, entity.label_)   
I did this but the ans is :  
(u'27ABcFA1565H1ZM', u'CARDINAL')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating your own train set, to have better results like explained [here](https://spacy.io/usage/training#section-basics).
You can use this tool to create your dataset [here](https://helkaroui.github.io/projects/entity_tagger.html)